# R - How can I store a dataframe in a vector by name without updating fields?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

How can I store a dataframe inside a vector `c()` by name, without replacing fields inside the vector?

I am trying to store a dataframe by name in a vector in the same way that I am able to store `Hello World` with the key `a_value`:

```r
> data <- c()
> data['a_value'] <- 'Hello World'
> data['a_value']
      a_value
"Hello World"
```

Now with the data frame:

```r
> data['loaded_csv'] <- read.csv('test.csv', header=TRUE, sep=',')
Warning message:
In data["loaded_csv"] <- read.csv("test.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",") :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I know that R is trying to replace/update fields of `data` with the columns loaded from the `read.csv` call, but I don't want to do that. I only want to associate the data frame from `read.csv(...)` with the key `loaded_csv` inside of `data`. I'm sure this is due to a misunderstanding on my part of how R uses vectors.

I'd like to be able to do this after storing it:

```r
loaded_csv <- data['loaded_csv']
```

Something similar in Python:

```py
data = {}
data['a_value'] = 'Hello World' # works!
data['loaded_csv'] = read_csv('test.csv')

loaded_csv = data['loaded_csv'] # works!
```

#### UPDATE: trying with `list()` instead of `c()`

Lists don't seem to make a difference :^/

```r
> data <- list()
> data['a_value'] <- 'Hello World'
> data['a_value']
$a_value
[1] "Hello World"

> data['loaded_csv'] <- read.csv('test.csv', header=TRUE, sep=',')
Warning message:
In data["loaded_csv"] <- read.csv("test.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",") :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: I think you might want a list rather than a vector

Comment: Hrmm, tried with the `list()`, maybe I'm doing something wrong (updated question to show `list()` attempt as well.

Comment: With lists you need to use `[[` rather than `[` to access/set a single item. `data <- list(); data[['a_value']] <- 'Hello World'; data[['loaded_csv']] <- read.csv(...)` should work.

Comment: See the [FAQ on single vs double brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/903061) for more details.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Used a list() and double brackets.